# Redirect when user reaches last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, touch

First off, I am not much of a programmer. I pieced together some code for making a slideshow that you use a swipe gesture to navigate forward and backwards on mobile devices. The problem I am having is that I need the user to be directed to another html page when they swipe on the last slide. I have tried placing "window.location =" calls in different places in the code but I can't get it to work anywhere. Here is my Markup and code. Am I using the wrong method or something?

```
<div id="slideWrap" class="slides">
<section id="slide1" class="mainSlides">
<h1>Slide 1</h1>
</section>

<section id="slide2">
<h1>Slide 2</h1>
</section>

<section id="slide3">
<h1>Slide 3</h1>
</section>

<section id="slide4">
<h1>Slide 4</h1>
</section>

<section id="slide5">
<h1>Slide 5</h1>
</section>

</div>

var currentSlide = 0;
$(function() {
$('.slides').swipe({
    swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        switch(direction) {
            case "left":
            next();
            break;
            case "right":
            back();
            break;
        }
    }
});

initSlides();
});

function initSlides() {
$("#slideWrap").html($('section').sort(function(){
return Math.random()-0.5;
}));

$('section').eq(currentSlide).addClass('active');
}

function next() {
goto(currentSlide+1);
};

function back(){
goto(currentSlide-1);
}

function goto(n){
if(n > -1 && n < $('section').length) currentSlide = n;
else return;
$('section').removeClass('active').eq(currentSlide).addClass('active');
}
```

Any insight will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't JavaScript code be inside `<script>` tags? (Serious question, not being sarcastic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page you want to redirect to is not local, you might want to call "window.location.href = {full url}" instead of "window.location = {relative path}"

Try this:

```
function goto(n){
  if(n > -1 && n < $('section').length) currentSlide = n;
  else if (n == $('section').length) window.location.href = "{url}";
  else return;
  $('section').removeClass('active').eq(currentSlide).addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Edward. That worked great. I tried putting the redirect there before but my condition was wrong and I used another if statement not an else if. Thanks again, you rock.